# Append two linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I wrote a simple method to append a linked list at the end of another linked list.So what the program should ideally do is when I give it two lists

```
list1 ===>1->2->3
list2 ===>4->5->6
```

updatedList `==>1->2->3->4->5->6`

But when I run the method `appendList` it goes into an infinite loop printing 1 to 6 indefinitely.What am I doing wrong out here?

```
public static Node appendList(Node head1, Node head2) {
    Node prev = null;
    Node current = head1;
    while (current != null) {
        prev = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    prev.next = head2;
    return head1;
}
```

Oh and I forgot to add the Node class and how I call the method from my main .I know its bit cumbersome but here it is

```
public class ReverseLinkedList {

class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void displayData() {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ReverseLinkedList reversedList = new ReverseLinkedList();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the length of  the linked list!!");
    int listSize = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the Numbers you want to insert!!");
    int count = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

        if (count == listSize)
            break;
        reversedList.insert(scanner.nextInt());
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Inserted List !!");
    reversedList.displayList();
    /*
     * Node reverseNodeStart =
     * reversedList.reverseList1(reversedList.first);
     * System.out.println("Reversed List !!"); while (reverseNodeStart !=
     * null) { reverseNodeStart.displayData(); reverseNodeStart =
     * reverseNodeStart.next; }
     */
    Node reverseNodeStart = reversedList.appendList(reversedList.first,
            reversedList.first);
    while (reverseNodeStart != null) {
        reverseNodeStart.displayData();
        reverseNodeStart = reverseNodeStart.next;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: There's no printing in that code, what is printing 1 to 6 in an infinite loop? Did you call `appendList(list2, list1)` too?

Comment: Are you sure the `head1` list doesn't have circular references? I would make 2 lists, 2 items each, and walk through the code in the debugger to see exactly what happens and what `current.next` points to when you are at the end of the list.

Comment: I made an edit please have a look!

Comment: I did put a debug point and when I reach the line 
prev.next = head2; 
head1 just becomes circular for some reason.How does this happen?

Comment: The problem was I was using the same List which was causing the circular reference.It works fine now.You knew the problem even before I posted the code now that's impressive. Thanks!!I solved it by creating a new List2
ReverseLinkedList reversedList2 = new ReverseLinkedList();
  reversedList2.insert(4);
  reversedList2.insert(5);
  reversedList2.insert(6);

Comment: @luckysing_noobster You are perfectly allowed to make your own answer (with the corrected code) and accept it if you were able to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using the same List which was causing the circular reference.It works fine now.You knew the problem even before I posted the code now that's impressive. Thanks!!I solved it by creating a new List2 and passing in List1 and List2.

```
  appendList(Node lis1head, Node list2head)
```